# Access Phone Hardware via Raspberry pi

Tags: camera, android, microphone, speakers

I want to access my Android Phone's Speaker, microphone, and camera via Raspberry pi.

Here are the Functions I want to perform :

**1. Play specific audio based on the Raspberry pi command.**

**2. Capture images and save them to the Raspberry pi SD card.**

**3. Capture audio when a sensor is triggered.**

Can these be achieved by simply connecting the phone vias USB/wifi to the pi board?
What other software is required to achieve this task.
Thank You for reading!!!

Comment: This probably needs some application running on the phone, but I don't know if such an application exists.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to look for the same, However, nothing exists where all these functions can be achieved. Have to try to make my own i think if nothing else works